# OTG Y cable provides power but doesn't show devices connected

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm running OTA-13 on a Nexus 4. I have a Y OTG cable. When I plug power into the Y and then the Y into the phone, it shows power. Then, when I plug a USB thumbdrive into the USB, it doesn't mount nor show any activity in the syslog. I've read elsewhere that this should work. Is the problem with my particular cable, or the micro-USB connector on the phone, or ? What should I try? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely the cable.

Answer (score 1):

A Y cable has two wires:

- One wire has power & data.
- The other wire has power only.

If you plug a data device into the power only wire it will not show up in Ubuntu. You have to plug it into the other wire "**power & data**".

It is impossible for a Y cable to have two data channels.